# ListView after click and back List is empty

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onclicklistener

I have a layout with a `ListView` and `ImageView`. Initially, `ImageView` is invisible. I have a list, when an Item is clicked, it shows the Image of that item by setting `ImageView` and making it visible and listView is invisible, so far everything is ok. From there, `onBackPressed()` I want to see my listview again, I override `onBackPressed()`, to make my image view invisible and listview visible. However, when I select an item and see the image of it then press back, a blank activity comes, not my listView. I don't want to call the activity again, what should I do? What is wrong about listView? I tried to call `invalidate()` and `invalidateViews()`, setting adapter again, but they aren't woring.

Actually I'm filing adapter in the onResume of the activity, here is the code:

```
public class MyViewActivity extends Activity{

    ListView imageList;
    CustomImageListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_list_view);

        //initialization of image array list etc
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        imageList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        adapter = new CustomImageListAdapter(this,R.layout.image_item, imageNames);
        imageList.setAdapter(adapter);
        imageList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int i,
                    long l) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(imageNames.get(i) != null) {
                    onImageSelected(i);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.image_list_view, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void onImageSelected(int position) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (img.getVisibility() == ImageView.VISIBLE){
//          img.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
//          imageList.invalidateViews();
//          imageList.setVisibility(ListView.VISIBLE);

// Here actually I want to use the upper part that I commented, but it didn't work, I have to call the same activity again to see my listview

            Intent i = new Intent(MyViewActivity.this, MyViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
        else {
            ....
        }

        return;
    }

    private class CustomImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        ...
}
```

Comment: You should **always** add the code you're trying, so other users may help you. Without code it's impossible.

Comment: You need to paste your code here. Well, try by calling youLlistview notifydatasetchanged();

Comment: i assume you are initially filling your adapter in the onCreate of the activity, try moving it to onResume. But its just a guess since there is no code

Comment: I added the activity code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as I can guess, the problem is caused by

```
img.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
```

You can try to use `View.GONE` instead.

The difference is clearly stated in android api's doc and I quoted:

> ```
> /**
>  * This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
>  */
> public static final int INVISIBLE = 0x00000004;
>
> /**
>  * This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout
>  */
> public static final int GONE = 0x00000008;
> ```

By the way, I will recommend to use **fragments** to do your job. Specifically, a fragment A to present the listview, and when an item is clicked, switch to fragment B which contains the content. When `Back` is pressed, just let  the backstack do its job.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MyViewActivity.this, MyViewActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("currentObjectID",objectID);
 startActivity(i);
 finish();
```

Why are you traversing within the same activity? You should understand the use of intents ,If you want to stay within the same activity , Just set a flag for `currentObjectID` instead of put Extra..

Comment: I think you dont understand my question, I dont want to call the same activity again, that part was my temporary solution!